# XPath for all nested text except "n" nested tags' text

Tags: xpath

I have following html.

```
<div id="content">
   <h3>Title</h3>
   <p>Some stuff</p>
   <p>other stuff</p>
   <p>other other stuff</p>
   <p>unnecessary stuff</p>
   <p>other unnecessary stuff</p>
</div>
```

I have written this expression so far.

```
//div[@id="content"]//text()
```

Which works but what I want is not to extract the text of last 2 `<p>` elements because that is unnecessary. I tried to write this...

```
//div[@id="content"]/p[not(position() > last() - 2)]//text()
```

Which did not work as expected. Then I tried this...

```
//div[@id="content"]/[not(self::p[position() > last() - 2])]//text()
```

Which also did not work.

Comment: xpath('//div[@id="content"]//text()').pop().pop()

Comment: can't use python functions. need xpath

Comment: If you need pure functional language for dom manipulation you can try XQuery.

Comment: Does that mean this is not possible in XPath expression?

Comment: Xpath just select elements but it doesn't manipulate you structures for this you should use XQuery.

Comment: Don't you think I'm trying to write an expression that select elements based on some condition and not manipulating anything? Because I know not(position > last() - 2) works somewhere else.

Comment: Place more code here, I need see more for further discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression returns the text nodes you are interested in:

```
//div[@id="content"]/*[not(self::p and position() > last() - 2)]//text()
```

You were missing an `*` after the `/`.

Comment: I had thought of it. Will give it a try and see.